# gtar fails to perform incremental backup

Tags: freebsd, backup, tar

The following script fails to perform incremental backup, but creates full backup instead.

On another FreeBSD server exactly same script works just fine (creating incremental backups).

Servers are identical, same FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE on both machines.
Script it exactly the same. Version of gtar is identical. File system is identical.

Not sure what's going on. Searched for days! Please help.

```
#!/bin/sh

sourcedir="/home"
targetdir="/backup/home"

now=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")

cd $sourcedir
for dir in */
do
  base=$(basename "$dir")
  gtar -cz -g "$targetdir/.gtar-incremental" -f "$targetdir/${base}-$now.tar.gz" "/home/$dir"
  chmod 600 "$targetdir/${base}-$now.tar.gz"
done
```

Comment: Can you pls try `gtar -cz -G "$targetdir/.gtar-incremental" -f "$targetdir/${base}-$now.tar.gz" "/home/$dir"`. Let us know how it went. A couple of examples I've seen suggest that `[ -g, --listed-incremental F ] [ -G, --incremental ]` [gtar manual](http://www.pkill.info/linux/man/1-gtar/)

Comment: That produced same result - full backup. I figured out that it got something to do with `for dir in */` loop, when I remove that and specify each directory/file - incremental works! Can you help? In addition to your comment `-G` can't take any arguments, it does not create a snapshot file.

Comment: I'll move the comment to the answer section as it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Spent sometime on this today, and I think there are two issues here:

1. every `for` loop iteration, a new incremental file is created (or old one is overwritten :-)
   . Remember, there is 1:1 mapping between the archive file and the snapshot file, thus one `gtar-incremental` can not serve all of the archive files.
2. `gtar` does not like time stamps.This is because the snapshot file stores the `tar.gz` file name, and if the string passed by `$now` is different than the old one it'll just create a new compressed file and new snapshot file.

The way I checked it, and incremental worked, was by changing the `gtar` line:

```
gtar --listed-incremental=$targetdir/gtar-incremental-$base  -cvzf $targetdir/$base.tar.gz $dir
```

This works in incremental.

The above will create `incremental` file for every directory that is being backed up.

Another way to get this to work w/o multiple `incremental` files is to backup the whole `home` directory as a whole instead of individual archives (i.e. w/o the `for` loop, just straight up `/home` to `/backup/home.tar.gz`).

Lastly, I was thinking if time stamps are important for you, you can add time stamp after the `gtar` is done to the files, and also remove the time stamp from the files (if exists before n > 2 run, can be constructed with `if` statement)

Are time stamps crucial for your operation?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. Because `/*` will give me each directory in the `/`. I'm looking to backup only `/home/*`

Comment: @Radio Awesome, than just change the `for` loop to always be `/home/*` .... I thought you want to backup the entire `/`

Comment: @Radio while describing `sourcedir` your `for` loop does not account for it. you should incorporate `$sourcedir` in your for loop.

Comment: yeah, i changed it to `for dir in $sourcedir/*` and `gtar -cz -g "$targetdir/.gtar-incremental" -f "$targetdir/$base-$now.tar.gz" "$dir"` - script runs ok, but still produces full backups! =(( Technically there is no different between my original script and what you suggested to change.

Comment: @Radio `$ for dir in $sourcedir/* ; do echo $dir; done` should work.... hmmm.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work. =) but gtar wont make incremental backups. it's interfering with that loop somehow. it's weird one. Once I remove that loop and specify each directory manually - gtar makes incrementals just fine.

Comment: @Radio , can you try addind `r` to `cz`

Comment: `gtar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option`

Comment: @Radio how abt this `$ for dir in "$sourcedir"/*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16327/discussion-between-radio-and-simply-me).